# nested list in beamer with numbers and bullets

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate, itemize, memory

I want to create a nested list in beamer exactly as follows:

[image]

This example is from https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Lists.

I tried many many examples using enumerate only, enumerate and itemize together, but none of them worked. Each time I received

```
./presentation.tex:63: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\labelenumi ->{
               \labelenumi } If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 36992 strings out of 492995
 742111 string characters out of 6132703
 881968 words of memory out of 5000000
 39840 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 34224 words of font info for 64 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 258i,11n,67p,10406b,808s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
./presentation.tex:63:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If I use only itemize everything is fine except that I can’t get the result I need.

As I understand using enumerate with beamer is not a good idea. How can I achieve this in this case? I am not perfect in latex, so I am looking for an easy to implement solution/idea.

I am using the code below:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame}

\begin{enumerate}

\item item 1

   \begin{itemize}
       \item bullet 1
       \item bullet 2
   \end{itemize}

\item item 2

   \begin{itemize}
       \item bullet 1
       \item bullet 2
   \end{itemize}

\item item 3

   \begin{itemize}
       \item bullet 1
       \item bullet 2
   \end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Can you show use the code that causes your problem? Nesting itemize inside enumerates usually works fine with beamer.

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `enumerate` package with beamer:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame}

\begin{enumerate}

\item item 1

   \begin{itemize}
       \item bullet 1
       \item bullet 2
   \end{itemize}

\item item 2

   \begin{itemize}
       \item bullet 1
       \item bullet 2
   \end{itemize}

\item item 3

   \begin{itemize}
       \item bullet 1
       \item bullet 2
   \end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tired that too but I still have the same error

Comment: @kneazle Can you add the .log file to your question?

Comment: Do you mean the whole file? Because I already shared the part where error message lies.

Comment: @kneazle I'm more interested in version numbers of the packages you use.

Comment: Is there a way to use different bulleted styles like dot for 1st level, arrow for 2nd and so on?